# Handbrake Crunches Out 4Kb File

Tags: mac, itunes, avi, handbrake, m4v

I've been using Handbrake to convert some movies to something I can put on my iPad or Apple TV. By in large it's been working great but I've noticed some of the avi's I toss at it come out as only ~4KB, obviously unusable, m4v's.

Is it possible to troubleshoot/correct?

Comment: Not a lot to go on here, I'm afraid. You've provided no information about the settings you use, the OS, your PC specs, or the source files (i.e. where they come from). It's entirely possible (based on my psychic analysis) that the AVIs which aren't converting, are corrupted in some or another way.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check ["How to request support for Handbrake"](https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?t=2741). There's also a [bug tracker](https://trac.handbrake.fr/search?q=&noquickjump=1&ticket=on&wiki=on).

Comment: My apologies for the lack of details. I'm using the Apple - Universal preset. The files are AVIs (old cartoons mostly) from years ago, not sure how they were originally ripped. What's odd is the vast majority rip fine, others result in this few kb file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with DVDFab rips (converting iso to m4v) whenever I left the menus intact in the ISO.  I'd get 4KB rips (even despite the fact that DVDFab had already removed copy protection).  So I'm not convinced this is just a copy protection issue - I think it's a legitimate bug in Handbrake (which I say gently since it's free software!).

For those troublesome ISOs, I load the ISOs into DVDFab again and remove menus, then the Handbrake rip goes just fine.